# Creating HTML parent tag using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I'm trying to add a parent `<div>` tag to my `<img>` tags.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"> 
        <title>submit demo</title> 
        <script src="D:\jquery\jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <form> 
            <div>   
                <textarea rows="50" cols="200"><p>This is a paragraph Tag</p>
                <p>
                    <img src='C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg'></img>this is a First paragraph tag
                </p>
                <p>
                    this is a second paragraph tag
                </p>
                <input type="submit"> 
            </div>
        </form>
        <span></span>
        <script>
            $("form").submit(function(event) {  
                event.preventDefault();
                var textarea = $("textarea").val();
                var Div = document.createElement("div");
                $(Div).html(textarea);
                var divtext = $(Div).html();

                $(Div).find("p:has(img)").each(function(i){
                    var images = $(this).html();
                    var d=document.createElement("div");
                    $(this).html("");
                    $(d).appendTo(this);
                    $(d).append(images);
                });

                $("textarea").val($(Div).html());
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here I need output like

```
<P>
    <DIV>
        <IMG src="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg"></IMG>
    </DIV>
    this is a second paragraph tag
</P>
```

Only the `<img>` tag should be inside my `<div>` tag but i'm getting output like

```
<P>
    <DIV>
        <IMG src="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg"></IMG>
        this is a second paragraph tag
    </DIV>
</P>
```

Please Help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `$('img').wrap('<div />');`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Answer (score 2):

Firstly the HTML you have for `img` tags is invalid. Try this:

```
<img src='C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg' />
```

Secondly, you need to use `wrap('<div />');` on them.

```
$('div img').wrap('<div />');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `.wrap()`, we can insert an HTML structure around the inner `<div> elements`.The new `<div> element` is created on the fly and added to the `DOM`. The result is a new `<div>` wrapped around each `matched element`

```
$( "img" ).wrap( "<div class='myClass'></div>" );
```

Output

```
<div class='myClass'><img src='C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg'></img></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `<textarea>` is not closed.

And the solution is wrap your **img** tag inside **Div**. This is so simple, with a single line of JQuery

```
$('img').wrap('<div />');
```

**or**

```
$('img').wrap('<div></div>');
```

You can add attributes to div if you want.